# Canonicalizing Arbitrary EBNF Expressions

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

From what I understand, LL and LR parsing require a grammar to be in "canonical form", i.e. only productions of the form `A -> b1 b2 ... bn`, where `b1`, ..., `bn` are either a terminal or a nonterminal. To express alternation, one would add multiple productions with the same LHS.

However, some EBNF expressions would require introducing new nonterminals, as for example a parenthesized group surrounded by other sequences: A production of the form `A -> a {b} c`* would have to be transformed to `A -> a A' c`, `A' -> b A' | ε`. By recursively "canonicalizing" productions we can obtain an equivalent grammar in canonical form.

Per se, this is not a huge problem, as the grammars are equivalent. But what if now we want to program a parser generator that supports arbitrary EBNF expressions? The parser developer would expect the generated AST to correspond to the structure of the grammar they defined. As the parser generator inserts new nonterminals, the parser developer is now facing nonterminals he's never heard of and doesn't know how to deal with them.

How is this problem usually solved? Do parser generators generally only allow grammars in canonical form? Or do they transform the grammar to a canonical form and later reconcile the AST to mirror the original structure?

* I believe this to be valid EBNF. I'm using `{x}` to denote zero or more repetitions of `x` and `[x]` to denote zero or one. `ε` denotes the empty string.

**"Appendix"**

I tried finding a way to simplify grammars to be canonical, without introducing new nonterminals. I found that it's possible for parenthesized groups, optional sequences and alternation. More specifically, I define the `simplify(x)` function, that "flattens" an EBNF expression. Top-level alternation can be canonicalized by splitting it into multiple productions. I make use of the distributivity of concatenation over alternation: `a(b|c) = ab|ac`. For arbitrary EBNF expressions `a` and `b`, let `a * b` be the equivalent expanded sequence of `ab`.

```
simplify(t)            = t               (for any terminal t)

simplify(A)            = A               (for any nonterminal A)

simplify(a1 a2 ... an) = simplify(a1)
                       * simplify(a2)
                       * ... 
                       * simplify(an)    (`*` is left-associative, but doesn't really matter)

simplify(a1|a2|...|an) = simplify(a1)
                       | simplify(a2)
                       | ...
                       | simplify(an)

simplify([a])          = simplify(a|ε)

simplify({a})          = ???             (here I got stuck)
```

I didn't find a way to "inline" a repetition, I believe this operation to be context sensitive (i.e. it is necessary to add a new non-terminal)

Comment: 1. "context sensitive" and "introduce a new non-terminal" are not synonyms. 2. It doesn't matter if you introduce a new non-terminal as long as you produce the correct parse tree (or, more generally, associate the correct attributes to each non-terminal).3. The more annoying problem is dealing with parsing conflicts artificially created by expanding EBNF operators. But lots of parser generators cope more or less successfully. Take a look at menhir, for example.

Comment: I'm aware that introducing a new non-terminal does not make the grammar context sensitive, I just meant that to simplify `{a}` you would need recursion, which requires knowledge about the LHS (thus it's not possible to rewrite `{a}` without knowing the left-hand context). Maybe worded it a bit badly.
I'll take a look at menhir or other parser generators to see how they deal with this, if at all.